# adding values of sub lists inside dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, sublist

After compiling the above cell, you should be able to compile the following cell and obtain the desired outputs.

this should return 36.

basically its adding edge weights of A,B,C,D. Some edges are listed twice which we should not add the weights for those if already accounted for. For example [A,B] and [B,A] since they are the same edge etc.

this the code I have so far that I can't get to work:

```
def infty(graph):
  sum = 0
  results = []
  for a in graph:
    for a in a:
      results.append(graph[a])
      sum = sum + results[a]
  print (sum)
```

Comment: is your graph always symmetric like the example?

Comment: I believe so, basically its adding edge weights of A,B,C,D. Some edges are listed twice which we should not add the weights for those if already accounted for. For example [A,B] and [B,A] since they are the same edge etc.

Comment: you may want to include some more pathological cases, if there are cases where some edges are listed twice but others only once. For example, what should be the result for `{'a':[['b', 1], ['c', 2]], 'b':[['a', 2]]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the graph is symmetric and its description is complete and consistent (i.e., for each weight `w_ab` there is an equal `w_ba`):

```py
def infty(g):
    return 1 + sum([e[1] for lst in g.values() for e in lst]) / 2
```

Example:

```py
g = {'A': [['B', 10], ['D', 5]], 'B': [['A', 10], ['C', 5]],
     'C': [['B', 5], ['D', 15]], 'D': [['C', 15], ['A', 5]]}

>>> infty(g)
36.0
```

**Explanation**

- `sum([e[1] for lst in g.values() for e in lst])` is simply a double list comprehension (a list comprehension with two `for` loops);
- the first for loop: `for lst in g.values()` iterates over the values of `g` (that is a `dict`), e.g.: `[['B', 10], ['D', 5]]`, then `[['A', 10], ['C', 5]]`, etc.);
- the second for loop: `for e in lst` iterates of each element in each list `lst`, e.g. `['B', 10]`, `['D', 5]`, etc.
- using `e[1]` refers to the weight of each edge.

Comment: Can you explain this portion of the code more: [e[1] for lst in g.values() for e in lst] im confused on the usage of two "for" in the same line. As well as the signifance for e[1]

Comment: What is the e[1] used for

Comment: ohh so e[0] is referring to the the letter representation and e[1] is referring to the weight. that makes a lot more sense. I was confused why it was called a sub list when to me it looked like a dictionary within a dictionary since the sub list seemed to have a key and a value but thats not the actual case correct?

Comment: please see the explanation in the updated answer. You may also want to google examples of Python list comprehensions. It is one of the most beautiful concepts in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre's answer is more elegant, but similarly to your first function, this seems to work for me :

```
def infty(graph):
    sum_ = 0
    for node in graph:
        for node_2 in graph[node]:
            sum_ += node_2[1]
    return (sum_)/2 +1
```

As in your example, graph is a dictionary. Nodes are counted twice, that is why  `sum_`is divided by 2. This works only in the case of a undirected graph.